# html links open first in notepad++

Tags: windows, html, file-association

I'm wondering where I could change the settings of opening html directly to a browser.
I have an HTML file but when I double clicked on it, it will open first the notepad++. 
I think I must have clicked on something. 
I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you clicked on something like "Associate HTML files" with Notepad++ while you installed it. You need to right click on HTML file, Open With -> Chose default program... and select your browser.